# GET parameter being received on server without quotes

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, get, webserver

I am working on a web application where on clicking a button on the UI a GET request is made to the server as below:

https://mywebapp.com?info=%5B%7B%22first%22%3A%22abcd%22%2C%22second%22%3A%22efgh%20ijkl%22%2C%22third%22%3A%22mnop%22%7D%5D

Basically the value I am passing as info is:

```
[{"first":"abcd","second":"efgh ijkl","third":"mnop"}]
```

However, when I read this passed value on server, I found it to be received as:

```
[{first:abcd,second:efgh ijkl,third:mnop}] i.e. all the double quotes are removed.
```

Now when I try to parse it into json, it fails.

Could you please suggest how could I fix the issue so that the json is received as expected.

Please note that it is an existing big application and I can't change any server level settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep the double qoutes as is you have to send the json in **single qoutes** 
i,e convert the json into string then send it, because the GET/POST request don't recognize json format